# IIS logs status code 590

Tags: iis-7, log-files, http-status-code

Background: Trying to chase a bug where resources occasionally won't load. Only happens on mobile devices.

Last five columns in IIS logs are `cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken`

What I don't understand is we have entries like:
`{..user agent..} 590 0 0 15`

If we map it, appears that some images return HTTP "590". Is there such a thing? I'm probably missing something here, any ideas?

Comment: User agent 590 is different from an http return code of 590.  But, for what it's worth, the only 59x http codes I'm aware of are 598 and 599, `Network read timeout error (Unknown)` and `Network connect timeout error (Unknown)`, respectively.  The fact that it only happens on mobile devices, and those error codes would make me suspect wireless connectivity issues, but that's all I've got.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It's not in the UA but in the sc-status column, which really bothers me because we all know there is no such kind of code.

Answer (score 1):

Just found out that the server was configured with an error page which outputs this "custom" status code.